# cassandra - port 7000 is not listening - how to make it "LISTEN"?

Tags: cassandra, port

> The connection to the port

[image: the connection to the port]

> one of the node that i need to connect to

[image: one of the node that i need to connect to]

> The ports are open

[image: the ports are open]

> The error

[image: the error]
trying to add a new cassandra node to a cluster,
after opening the port (7000) i can connect to him, but he is not "LISTEN" mode.

please advise how to fix that

Comment: Please post error messages and output as text, not as images.

Answer (score 1):

So the second line of your `netstat` output tells me about what is happening here.

```
tcp    0    0 10.142.0.3:7001    0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN
```

Port 7000 is used for inter-node communication within the cluster...  *Unless SSL is enabled*.  Then port 7001 is used.

- Try port 7001 instead.
- You're going to need a SSL cert from the same CA (certificate authority) as the other nodes in the cluster.

For SSL, have a look at the `server_encryption_options` and the `client_encryption_options` in the cassandra.yaml on the other nodes.  That should give you a pretty good idea of what you need to connect.